# QFT Superposition and the Higgs Ground State

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, measurement-problem, higgs

In a quantum theory with zero spatial dimensions with Hamiltonian given by:
$$H = \pi^\dagger \pi + \mu^2 \phi^\dagger \phi - \lambda (\phi^\dagger \phi)^2,$$ where the non hermitian field, $\phi$, is related to hermitian ones by $$\phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\begin{array}{c}\phi_0 + i \phi_1 \\
\phi_2 + i \phi_3 \end{array}\right],$$ and the equal time commutation relations are: $$\begin{align}[\phi_i, \phi_j] & = 0, \\
[\pi_i, \pi_j] & = 0, \ \mathrm{and}\\
[\phi_i, \pi_j] & = i\hbar \delta_{ij}. \end{align}$$ The potential has a classic "Mexican hat" shape, and I would expect the ground state to be a superposition that is invariant under $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ rotations of the complex coordinate, similar to how the [ground state of the ammonia molecule](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node255.html) is the symmetric superposition of the nitrogen atom being on either side of the hydrogen plane.

The above Hamiltonian is what you would expect for a Higgs field in zero spatial dimensions. When spatial dimensions are added, the Hamiltonian density is:$$\mathcal{H} = \pi^\dagger \pi + \left(\nabla \phi^\dagger\right) \cdot \left(\nabla \phi^{\vphantom{\dagger}}\right) + \mu^2 \phi^\dagger \phi - \lambda (\phi^\dagger \phi)^2.$$

As long as the state is translation invariant, the gradient terms in the Hamiltonian won't affect the above considerations, so why does the ground state have a non-zero vacuum expectation value (vev)? In the symmetric superposition the vev is $0$. Even if the ground state isn't unique, because the $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ degrees of freedom of the field are non-dynamical (i.e. they don't contribute to the kinetic term), why would the state assume a configuration that has a particular vev? Most treatments of the Higgs mechanism calculate the vev as $|\mu|\left/\sqrt{\lambda}\right.$, the vev for a maximally asymmetric state.

The analogy usually given for this process is ferromagnetism, where the direction that a particular magnetic domain points is not fixed by the Hamiltonian, but the part of the Hamiltonian that describes the interactions between the atoms does favor all of them in a domain pointing in the same direction. The difference in this scenario is that the magnetic domain is macroscopic, so its inability to assume a superposition of directions is a matter settled by the measurement problem. Does this mean that decoherence or some other solution of the measurement problem is what causes ground state to have a non-zero vev? If so, a description of the process, or link to one, would be appreciated.

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243291/superposition-of-distinct-vevs-in-spontaneous-symmetry-breaking).

Comment: The answer given doesn't completely handle what I've asked. The infinite separation holds for states related by a discrete symmetry, but this is a continuous symmetry where states of different vev are always separated by an infinitesimal energy, no matter how large the space.

Comment: Nice question. Weinberg's QFT Vol. 2, section 19.1, addresses exactly this issue (and he even suggests an analogy with a chair!). I can't say that I fully understand the details so I cannot answer with my own words, but it is a good reference.