# For a continuous symmetry breakdown, why is a superposition of all vacua impossible?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

I understand that for a **discrete** symmetry breakdown where the wave functional for your field has two vacua, say $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$, the reason why the true groundstate can't be a superposition of these two is because they are separated by a potential barrier and, assuming the field extends over an infinite volume, the total energy barrier is infinite. So tunneling is impossible.

But let's say you have a **continuous** symmetry and a Mexican hat potential. Then you have infinitely many vacua, denoted by $|\theta\rangle$ where $0\le\theta<2\pi$. If I pick two of these states, say $|0\rangle$ and $|\varepsilon\rangle$ where $\varepsilon$ is infinitesimal, the potential barrier between them is zero: the two states have the same energy and are next to each other, so tunneling should be permitted. And then once you have tunneled from $|0\rangle$ to $|\varepsilon\rangle$, you can tunnel to $|2\varepsilon\rangle$ then $|3\varepsilon\rangle$ and so on all the way back to $|0\rangle$. You will then have a superposition of all such states, and the superposition would respect the symmetry.

Except that doesn't happen. Where's the flaw in the reasoning?

Comment: The vacua are disjoint. It takes infinite energy to tunnel from one vacuum to the next for a infinite system. Goldstone modes will not take you from one vacuum to another.

Comment: Related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/243291/

Comment: @Bruce The answer to that question doesn't fully solve my confusion. Peter says that any matrix element between two vacua vanishes, and I know this needs to be the case, but I don't **why**. For discrete symmetries, there's the intuitive notion that you have a potential barrier multiplied by an infinite volume, but I don't know how the same idea would apply for continuous symmetry, since one vacuum can be right next to the other, without barrier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that rotating the value of the field at a single point by an infinitesimal amount only costs infinitesimally small energy $\epsilon$.  But to take the field into a new ground state, you need to rotate the field value at *every* point.  So the total energy cost is $E = \epsilon V$, where the local energy cost $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal but the total spacetime volume $V$ is infinite.  Whether $E$ ends up infinitesimal, finite, or infinite depends on the order of limits - is $\epsilon$ "smaller than $V$ is infinite?"  Your simple intuitive argument isn't precise enough to answer that question - you need to do a calculation.  And if you do so, it turns out that the total energy cost $E$ to tunnel between different vacua is infinite, but you do get Goldstone mode excitations which *locally* (though not globally) take you into a different ground state, and these Goldstone modes can have arbitrarily low energy (although strictly speaking not *zero* energy, because an *exactly* zero energy Goldstone mode isn't an excitation at all, and just leaves you in the original ground state).

Comment: _"but you do get Goldstone mode excitations which locally (though not globally) take you into a different ground state"_ I intuitively understand this. But what does it mean mathematically? Different vacua are disjoint but still Goldstone modes locally connect them in some manner. Which Hilbert space does a Goldstone mode belong to? @tparker